# Sequentially open and close Internet Explorer with URL's from an Array in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

My requirement is to open `InternetExplorer`, wait till the page loads, Close that particular instance of `IE`, and do the same for the rest of the urls.

The URL's are saved in an Array.

Attaching the code I have done so far.

I'm just opening the Browser, passing Url as a parameter, and killing the process.

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
foreach (var WebPage in YearUrlLoop)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo Browser = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe", WebPage);
            Process p = Process.Start(Browser);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            p.WaitForExit();
            Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("IEXPLORE");
            foreach (Process prc in ps)
            {
                prc.Kill();
            }
}
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Console? If it has a GUI use a WebBrowser control and the DocumentCompleted event instead of IE.

Comment: Hey, its not from a GUI. This is part of a SSIS script task where the requirement to cache reports post data load. There are a lot of conditions that have to be met so running the URl's is the solution we have ended up with. As for your suggestion, DocumentCompleted event can be used, but i need the Process to be looped for every WebPage in the Array. Not sure if invoking the DocumentCompleted Event is the best way forward.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO on using DocumentCompleted in a loop, it's the only way to guarantee the page fully loaded before loading the next one. Your way could work (if you remove `p.WaitForExit()` and just put `p.Kill();`) but there's no guarantee the page loaded before you kill the process.

Comment: Guessing i'm wrong here but,  how does the DocumentCompleted fare against WebBrowser.ReadyState. I'm new to the  whole events and Event Handlers subject. And can you please give me the code using Document.Completed event for the above requirement. Thanks a ton!!